# Three tables side by side, want only one caption

Tags: tables, floats, minipage

I have three tables and I want to use one caption under them. I tried the following but then nothing prints except the caption -

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular}[t]{|c | c | c | c |}
                \hline
                State                      & $1$-step      \\ \hline
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
                $\ket{n, \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
                $\ket{n, \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular}[t]{|c | c | c | c |}
                \hline
                State                     & $2$-step      \\ \hline
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\ \hline

                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}        
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular}[t]{|c | c | c | c |}
                \hline
                State                     & $3$-step \\ \hline
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
                $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\

                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}    
    \end{table}
\caption{Directions}
\end{figure}
```

If I remove the figure and begin{figure}, end{figure}, and caption{} tags, the tables show but there is no caption. So how can I get the tables to show with the caption?

Comment: Do not *nest* the floating environments. Use the outer float as `table`, and remove the inner `table` environment. You can just use `tabular` to set you tables.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. Please always post a _complete_ document so people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: as Werner said, and also you don't need the minipages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can't* really nest floating environments (it doesn't make sense logically). That's the main problem, and may stem from the fact that you think you *need* a `table` environment in order to place a `tabular`. That's not the case. You're probably after the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{| c | c |}
        \hline
        State                      & $1$-step      \\ \hline
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\hfill%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{| c | c |}
        \hline
        State                     & $2$-step      \\ \hline
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\hfill%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{| c | c |}
        \hline
        State                     & $3$-step \\ \hline
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Directions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You may also be interested in a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c c}
        \toprule
        State                      & $1$-step      \\ \midrule
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\hfill%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c c}
        \toprule
        State                     & $2$-step      \\ \midrule
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\hfill%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c c}
        \toprule
        State                     & $3$-step \\ \midrule
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}$   & $\leftarrow$  \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}$   & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}$  & $\rightarrow$ \\
        $\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}$  & $\leftarrow$  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Directions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As an aside: You could have placed the entire table into a single `tabular` as well.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to getting rid of the `table` and `minipage` "wrappers", you could also use `array` environments instead of `tabular` environments. I suggest this because the contents of the tables are all in math mode, and `array` environments are meant to be used for math material. (`tabular` environments, in contrast, are meant for tables that contain mostly text.) Being able to dispense with all those `$` signs simplifies the look of the code considerably, I think.

[image]

PS It wasn't clear to me if you want the overall floating environment to be of type `figure` or `table`. In the example I've selected `figure`, but that may not be what you prefer. If you'd rather have the caption list "Table" than "Figure", just change the type of floating environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket,amsmath} % 'amsmath' for `\text` macro
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
$ % start math mode
\begin{array}[t]{|c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\text{State}  & \text{1-step} \\ \hline
\ket{n, \leftarrow, 0}   & \leftarrow  \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow, 1}   & \rightarrow \\
\ket{n, \rightarrow, 0}  & \rightarrow \\
\ket{n, \rightarrow, 1}  & \leftarrow  \\
\hline
\end{array}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{array}[t]{|c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\text{State} & \text{2-step}  \\ \hline
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}   & \leftarrow  \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}   & \rightarrow \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}  & \rightarrow \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}  & \leftarrow  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{array}[t]{|c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\text{State} & \text{3-step} \\ \hline
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 0}   & \leftarrow  \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \leftarrow, 1}   & \rightarrow \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 0}  & \rightarrow \\
\ket{n, \leftarrow,  \leftarrow,  \rightarrow, 1}  & \leftarrow  \\
\hline
\end{array}   
$ % end math mode
\caption{Directions}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```